# Is every group (Z/nZ, +) isomorphic to some subgroup of $(Z/mZ)^\times$? If not, find all n for which this doesn't hold

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

**My progress on this so far**:

($\mathbb{Z}$/$n\mathbb{Z}$, $+$) is basically the cyclic group $C_n$. So the question boils down to if there is an element $x$ of order $n$ for any $n$ in the group  $(\mathbb{Z}$/$m\mathbb{Z})^\times $, because then $\langle x\rangle = (x, x^2, x^3,...,x^{m-1}, e)$ forms a cyclic group of order $m$.

The question can then also be formulated as the problem of finding $S$ where $$S = \{ n : \not\exists a, m \in \mathbb{Z}^+ s.t. a^n \equiv 1\ (mod\ m)\}$$

Or as

$$ S = \{ n : n\  \text{is not the order of any number a mod any number m }\}$$

From this I can definitely conclude that $x \in S\ if\ \forall  n\ x \nmid \phi(n) $, because of [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), but I guess that doesn't really give us anything.

I'm not sure if this is the way I should be going about the problem, and if it is then I am not sure on how I should proceed further.

Comment: You understand that $\;\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z\;$ is **not** a subgroup under multiplication modulo $\;m\;$ , right? Thus, your question makes no sense...

Comment: @DonAntonio $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is a group under multiplication modulo $m$, and as a group it can have subgroups which are what I'm referring to

Comment: No, it is not a group. For example, what would be the unit element under multiplication modulo $\;n\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n .  I think I've mixed up some notation, but those are the groups I wanted to refer to

Comment: @Peew Then **you** look up that. It seems to be you meant the group **of units modulo** $\;m\;$ , which is way another thing than what you wrote. Please check this carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Outline of proof:

1) for prime $p > 2$ $(\Bbb Z/p^k)^*$ is cyclic (of order $p^{k-1}(p-1)$, obviously)

2) $(\Bbb Z/2^k)^*$ is $\Bbb Z/2$ times cyclic

(it's part of Gauss primitive root theorem)

3) use Chinese remainder theorem to obtain general description of $(\Bbb Z/n)^*$